# Make my nav responsive

Tags: html, css

I would like to make my navigation responsive to a changing screen size. So, when the screen minimises to 600 or 800px, I'd like the navigation to move to the top of the screen and maybe be replaced by a small menu image which drops down.

I'm a complete beginner here, and this is also my first post on stackoverflow, so I'm still learning how to code and would really appreciate some advice.

Thanks!

```css
body{
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 background-color: #f6be21;
 margin-right: 20px;
}

/* reset margin on all elements */

* {
 margin: 0;

}

.blurb{
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: left;
 width: 45%;
 color: #ffffff;
 list-style: none;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 60px;
 margin-top: 60px;
 position: absolute;
 padding-bottom: 100px;
}


.big-number-1{
 font-size: 70px;
 text-align: right;
 clear: both;
}

#main-header {
 text-align: right;
 width: 100%;
 float: right;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 275px;
 height: 20px;
 right: 50px;
 clear: both;
}

.nav li + li:before{
 content: "/";
 padding: 0 9px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

ul.nav > li {
 display: inline;
 list-style: none;
 text-decoration: none;

}

ul.nav{
 list-style: none;
 display: inline;
}

h1.title{ 
 font-size: 53.34px; 
 color: #000000;
}

a.h1{
 text-decoration: none;  
}

a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000000;
}

a:visited{
 color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<header id="main-header">
        <h1 class="title"><a href="index.php">Chris Ioannou</a></h1>

        <ul class="nav">

            <li>
                <a>.01 about</a>
            </li>
            
            <li>
                <a href="read.html">.02 read</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        
        <div class="big-number-1">
   <h3>.01<h3>
    
    </header>
```

Comment: you can either look into creating your  own media queries or look into adding boot strap as this handles the responsive side of the website

Comment: We are here to help you figure out why, what you tried, doesn't work but we aren't here to write markup and code for you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @rob thanks for the link, i'll read through the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a class `.blurb` which I have removed, has I couldn't find that in your `html tags`. `Second` there are `framework` through which you can make your work `responsive` or use `media query to style at different break points` as I have used here in your code to changes `background-color` after certain `width` and position content to `top`, as below,

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
body{
   background:red; 
}
#main-header{
    top:0;
  }
}
```

```css
body{
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 background-color: #f6be21;
}

/* reset margin on all elements */

* {
 margin: 0;

}


.big-number-1{
 font-size: 70px;
 text-align: right;
}

#main-header {
 text-align: right;
 width: 100%;
 float: right;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 275px;
 height: 20px;
 right: 50px;
 clear: both;
}

.nav li + li:before{
 content: "/";
 padding: 0 9px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

ul.nav > li {
 display: inline;
 list-style: none;
 text-decoration: none;
}

ul.nav{
 list-style: none;
 display: inline;
}

h1.title{ 
 font-size: 53.34px; 
 color: #000000;
}

a.h1{
 text-decoration: none;  
}

a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000000;
}

a:visited{
 color: #000000;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
  body{
   background:red; 
 }
#main-header{
    top:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="main-header">
        <h1 class="title"><a href="index.php">Chris Ioannou</a></h1>

        <ul class="nav">

            <li>
                <a>.01 about</a>
            </li>
            
            <li>
                <a href="read.html">.02 read</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        
        <div class="big-number-1">
   <h3>.01<h3>
    
    </header>
```

Comment: This works well, thanks for illustrating what I can do :)

Comment: Welcome @Chris :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:.. this will move the header to the top of the screen on smaller devices. you can check this in google chrome on the developer tool bar.

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 375px)
and (max-device-width: 480px) {
   #main-header {
     top: 0px !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways you can accomplish that, but I strongly recommend you to dive into the wonderful world of HTML, CSS and JS **Frameworks**. I would suggest starting with the **Bootstrap Framework** (http://getbootstrap.com/). It's easy to use and it comes with handy components.

For example, the **Navbar** component, with which you can do the menu thing you want in different screen sizes:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Hope it helps!